# SQL Show the values in a count()

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two Tables:

```
  People                    Jobs

id | name            id | personId | Status | place
--------------      ---------------------------------
1  | John            1  |    1     | Active | Home
2  | Melinda         2  |    1     | Active | Office
3  | Samuel          3  |    2     | Active | Home
                     4  |    3     | Active | Office
                     5  |    1     | Active | Garden
```

**Problem:**

I want to display the names of the people who have more than one active job either on Home or Office. I could do the count and display the number but I can't diplay the names.

Here is my code (which isn't working):

```
SELECT t.name 
FROM people p JOIN jobs j ON j.personId = p.id
WHERE j.status = 'Active' AND j.place='Home' OR j.place='Office' 
HAVING count(j.personId) > 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your AND and OR are mixed in WHERE condition:

change this

```
 WHERE j.status = 'Active' AND j.place='Home' OR j.place='Office'
```

to

```
  WHERE j.status = 'Active' AND (j.place='Home' OR j.place='Office')
```

TRY this

```
 SELECT p.name 
 FROM People p JOIN jobs t ON t.personId = p.id
 WHERE t.status = 'Active' AND (t.place='Home' OR t.place='Office')
 GROUP BY p.name
 HAVING count(t.personId) > 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/202cf6/8)

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM people p JOIN jobs j ON j.personId = p.id
WHERE j.status = 'Active' AND (j.place='Home' OR j.place='Office') 
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING count(j.personId) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're consolidating the data but with no 'GROUP BY':

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM people p JOIN jobs j ON j.personId = p.id
WHERE j.status = 'Active' AND j.place='Home' OR j.place='Office'
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING count(j.personId) > 1
```

However I'd have tried this first (will be a lot more efficient if the lpace data is skewed but you might have to force an index):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name 
FROM people p
INNER JOIN jobs j1
   ON p.id=j1.personId
   AND j1.status='Active'
   AND j1.place='Home'
INNER JOIN jobs j2
   ON j1.personId=j2.personId
   AND j2.status='Active'
   AND j2.place='Office'
```

Comment: Didn't try but looks a little confusing for me. The answer I voted correctly is actually pretty good and it's working. Check it out!
Thanks for your contribution anyways :)